# When I upgrade the PCL version from 1.13.0 to 1.13.1，It probably means that the reference count error causes a problem with the release of resources

Tags: 3d, pcl

when i upgrade the PCL version from 1.13.0 to 1.13.1, an exception will be thrown when I run the following code and return. It probably means that the reference count error causes a problem with the release of resources.
The code is:

```
using FrCloud = pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>;
using FrPointType =  pcl::PointXYZI;
using FrCloudPtr = pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>::Ptr;

int run()
{
 FrCloudPtr myCurrentClouds;
 myCurrentClouds = myCameraClouds[myCameraWorkList.front()];
 FrCloudPtr filter_clouds(new FrCloud);

 pcl::PassThrough<FrPointType> ptfilter(true);
 ptfilter.setInputCloud(myCurrentClouds);
 ptfilter.setFilterFieldName("x");
 ptfilter.setFilterLimits(myPassFilterParams.minDistanceX, myPassFilterParams.maxDistanceX);
 ptfilter.setKeepOrganized(myKeepOrganized);
 ptfilter.filter(*filter_clouds);

 ArLog::log(ArLog::Normal, "passthrough filter: %ld [msec]", tm.mSecSince());
 return 0;
}
```

throws an exception when the function returns：

```
    void _Destroy() noexcept override { // destroy managed resource
        _Destroy_in_place(_Storage._Value);
    }
```

I can’t see any problems with this code, so what causes it throws the exception？

Comment: Which operating system do you use? How did you install PCL? Can you provide a trace of the exception?

Comment: my enviroment:
os: Windows 11 
visual sutdio:  Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64 bit) - Current
Version 17.7.3
pcl: PCL-1.13.1-AllInOne-msvc2022-win64.exe
I install the PCL library through the installation package, and then link PCL lib by cmakelist. The cmakelist code is as follows:
macro(setpcl)
set(PCL_DIR ${PCL_ROOT}/cmake/PCLConfig.cmake)
find_package(PCL 1.13.1 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})
endmacro()

Answer (score 0):

my enviroment:
os: Windows 11
visual sutdio: Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64 bit) - Current Version 17.7.3
pcl: PCL-1.13.1-AllInOne-msvc2022-win64.exe
I install the PCL library through the installation package, and then link PCL lib by cmakelist. The cmakelist code is as follows:
macro(setpcl)
set(PCL_DIR ${PCL_ROOT}/cmake/PCLConfig.cmake)
find_package(PCL 1.13.1 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})
endmacro()

[debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hav98.png)

[debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSwd3.png)

Comment: Rather than adding details as an answer, please [edit] your question to add information. Editing your question ensures all relevant information is together. Posting as a question clutters the environment. Furthermore, when you edit your post, please ensure that you **do not post images of text**. Instead, put the text itself so that people do not have to retype it and so that screen readers are able to read it.